# cryWhat algorithm are Trezor One and Trezor T using to sign messages?

Tags: encryption, elliptic-curves, cryptocurrency

My knowledge of cryptography is beyond shallow, and I have a problem I cannot solve.

Trezor wallets have two message signing formats: "Trezor" and "Electrum".

I have a method in my code, that is retrieving the public key from messages signed using BTC wallets (i am using `bitcoinj` library):

```
public VerificationStatus verifyMessage(String walletAddress, String phrase, String signature) {
    Address signingAddress = null;
    Address addressFromKey = null;
    try {
        signingAddress = Address.fromString(null, walletAddress);
        ECKey ecKey = ECKey.signedMessageToKey(phrase, signature);
        addressFromKey = Address.fromKey(signingAddress.getParameters(), ecKey, signingAddress.getOutputScriptType());
    } catch (SignatureException exception) {
        LOGGER.error(exception.getMessage());
    }
    return determineVerificationStatus(signingAddress, addressFromKey);
}
```

When I sign a message using either Electrum wallet or Trezor with the option "Electrum" format selected, everything works fine.

Example data for Electrum signed message:

> address: bc1qpluptcvxpvyzsmqzy8jrmdt3m985t6z95s24nu
> message: MESSAGE
> signature: H41bIfNhn1vT5yzgFUA3rZE7FNCM8epMrINVbzOefOImYs42hEIUHuoY/UkMd9ljjYkaci7fVJgCTUE6hPJN3Cg=

But when I try to use the "Trezor" format, for which the signature looks different:

> address: bc1qpluptcvxpvyzsmqzy8jrmdt3m985t6z95s24nu
> message: MESSAGE
> signature: J41bIfNhn1vT5yzgFUA3rZE7FNCM8epMrINVbzOefOImYs42hEIUHuoY/UkMd9ljjYkaci7fVJgCTUE6hPJN3Cg=

I get an `SignatureException` thrown by `ECKey.signedMessageToKey(phrase, signature);`, with an exception message:

> Header byte out of range: 40

As I mentioned at the beginning of this question: my knowledge about cryptography is almost non-existent, but from what I suspect - Trezor is signing the message using something else, another algorithm, and this causes the `ECKey.signedMessageToKey()` method throw an exception telling that header byte is out of range

My question is - how is Trezor creating the signature using the so called "Trezor format", and how could I solve this problem programatically?